# Emacs 28.1 hangs up with Emacs Speaks Statistics (ESS) package in Fedora 36

Tags: emacs, fedora, ess

My Fedora 36 upgraded Emacs to version 28.1. today, and Emacs no longer starts up. Emacs gets stuck displaying message saying it is loading `site-start/ess-init.el`. Furthermore, Emacs spawns a bunch of other `emacs` processes, say 10, and nothing happens until the system runs out of resources.

Any idea of why this happens?

I have found out the following:

- The only line in `ess-init.el` is

  ```
  (require 'ess-site)
  ```
- The package providing `ess-site.el` is `emacs-ess-18.10.2-6.fc36.noarch`, which comes with the system.
- File `ess-site.el` has a byte-compiled version, which seems to be for Emacs v23:

  ```
  sh-5.1$ pwd
  /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess
  sh-5.1$ ls -l ess-site.el*
  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4812 Nov 10  2018 ess-site.el
  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1869 Jan 20 03:57 ess-site.elc
  sh-5.1$ file ess-site.elc
  ess-site.elc: Emacs/XEmacs v23 byte-compiled Lisp data
  ```
- Removing ESS from the system removes the issue.

Edit: According to [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html#Byte-Compilation), byte compilation for older version of Emacs should not be be an issue if the older version is "recent," whatever that may mean:

```
In general, any version of Emacs can run byte-compiled code produced by recent earlier versions of Emacs, but the reverse is not true.
```

Comment: I don't vote for Close. But it seems to me that this question would be better placed somewhere in the Fedora Community or minimal at https://unix.stackexchange.com/. Because it is distro specific I also wouldn't recommend to place it at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good point, but I honestly do not know whether it is specific to this distribution. Perhaps it is about Emacs 28.1. interacting with ESS. Or then it is about how older byte-compiled files work in Emacs 28.1.

Comment: What is ESS? Where does ess-site.el comes from? Never seen this file before.

Comment: ESS is Emacs Speaks Statistics (https://ess.r-project.org/). It allows, for example, convenient interaction between Emacs and R.

Comment: Can you manually byte compile `ess-site.el`, re-enable ESS and see if emacs is happier?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be one or more bugs with emacs' add on packages on Fedora.  The Fedora project uses the Red Hat Bugzilla system for tracking bugs.  Information about this particular issue can be tracked in [bug 2108993 at bugzilla.redhat.com](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2108993)